# Persistent Storage in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I want to have persistent or persistent-ish storage in a Chrome extension - so what I'm currently trying to do is create an Indexeddb database, and query that from another page.

Here's something from one of my content scripts:

```
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({
            "type": "search",
            "text": char
        },
```

Which calls this:

```
search: function(text) {
    var entry = this.db_query(text);
    if (entry != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.data.length; i++) {
            var word = entry.data[i][1];
        }
    }
    return entry;
}
```

Which goes here:

```
db_query: function(text) {
    var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    console.log(background);
    var open = indexedDB.open("CEDICT", 1);
    var db = open.result;
    var tx = db.transaction("CEDICT", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("CEDICT");
    var index2 = store.index("simplified");

    var getData = index2.get(text);

    getData.onsuccess = function() {
        console.log(getData.result);
        return getData.result;
};


    tx.oncomplete = function() {
    db.close();
};
},
```

Which however is providing an empty indexedDB, despite this being in a background script:

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

var open = indexedDB.open("CEDICT", 1);

open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    var db = open.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore("CEDICT", {autoIncrement:true});
    var index1 = store.createIndex("traditional", 'traditional');
    var index2 = store.createIndex("simplified", 'simplified');
};

open.onsuccess = function() {
    var db = open.result;
    var tx = db.transaction("CEDICT", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("CEDICT");

store.put({"traditional": "三體綜合症", "simplified": "三体综合症", "tones": ["1", "3", "1", "2", "4"]});
store.put({"traditional": "□", "simplified": "□", "tones": ["1"]});
store.put({"traditional": "○", "simplified": "○", "tones": ["2"]});
```

etc...

```
tx.oncomplete = function() {
    db.close();
};
```

Why is indexedDB empty? Am I doing something wrong? The first time I reloaded the plugin after adding this, it worked correctly, giving me values I wanted, but since then it hasn't worked and it has returned empty values.

Here's an error I get:

```
_generated_background_page.html:1 Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished.
```

Does this just mean I need a promise or something?

Comment: Have you checked the `chrome.storage` api? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Won’t work for a huge database like I have

Comment: Your `var db = open.result;` assignment in the `db_query` function seems to be the problem, you should wait until the database is open. Another thing... Your `return getData.result` won't return to the caller of the `db_query`, it will return to event emitter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the value from `return getData.result;` as the code suggests. You will need to become more familiar with async js to use indexedDB.

Just to give a brief example, pretend you had a button, and an event listener on this button. Could you return a value from the event listener function? No. Similarly, you cannot return the value here.

Briefly, you can pass the result to a callback function instead. Or use a promise.

```
function db_query(..., callbackFunction) {
  getData.onsuccess = function(){
    // Instead of returning, call the callback function
    callbackFunction(getData.result);
  };
}
```

Then, instead of getting the result of db_query, you instead continue execution within the callbackFunction body.

```
db_query(..., function myCallback(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: I was going to eventually move that into a promise if it was an issue, though I don’t think it is as it’s a whole different part of the Chrome extension (background page vs the content scripts, which run on the main page). The issue I need to know about is why indexdb is empty

Comment: I know that when the database is full, it returns the data where I want it